# Exchange Server Mailbox Migration speed issues

Tags: exchange-2016

I have an issue with my Exchange servers failing to migrate mailboxes at any kind of speed.

There are two Exchange 2016 instances running a single DAG which has 4 databases - two of the DBs are the original ones I'm trying to move away from and the other two are new, target, DBs for where the data should end up.

It's continuously getting snarled up with disk latency and other such issues.

I understand that Exchange throttles so not to cause an impact to the user experience, but at this stage I need to get the data out of the current DBs and into new ones on a different drive before the current drive runs out of space. (I can't expand the current drive because there seems to be an issue with disk management/ReFS where expanding it gets it into a messed up state).

Does anyone know how I can disable every piece of throttling that the servers may be doing so that the migration can continue quickly?

At this stage I don't really care about whether this impacts user experience as I'm imagining that running out of space on the drive where the DBs currently are would have a significantly worse impact for our users.